# How to fix my Array class

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to get my array to run correctly, I know I have to change the array value to an input but I cannot get the program to compile if any one can help that be great.
I am trying to have the program take input for grades and names of students and in the end output their name and grade.
**Edit** sorry this is my first it posting i have an error 
**Student.java:60: error: class, interface, or enum expected** I am in java 101 so this is why it is such low level java, we only know the basics

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class students
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("How many students?: ");
      int numofstudents = keyboard.nextInt();

      Student s = new Student();

      s.setMultipleStudents();
      s.toString();


      System.out.println("Enter the Grade for the student: ");
      int gradeofstudnets = keyboard.nextInt();


   }
}
```

and my second class is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student
   {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String name;
    private int grade;
    private int[] multiplegradeinputs = new int[10];
    private String[] multipleStudent = new String[10];

    public Student()
    {
    }

    public Student(String n, int g)
    {
      name = n;
      grade = g;
    }

    public  String setMultipleStudents()
    {
      String n = "";
      for(int i = 1; i < multipleStudent.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter student #" + i +" name: " );
         n = scan.nextLine();
         multipleStudent[i] = n;

      }

      return null;
    }



    public String multiplegradeinputs()
    {
      for(int i = 1; i <multiplegradeinputs.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter the Grade of the student#" + i +" : ");
         grade = scan.nextInt();
         multiplegradeinputs[i] = grade;
      }
    } <--- error here

    public String toString()
    {
      String temp = "";
       for(int i = 1; i < multipleStudent.length; i++)
      {
         temp += multipleStudent[i] + " ";
      }

      return temp;

    }
}
```

Comment: What are the compile errors?

Comment: You've provided extremely minimal details here. If you want help, you need to explain WAY more about what your program is supposed to do and what the specific problems are that you're encountering.

Comment: Java's an object oriented language.  Separate arrays of student and grade don't feel like good encapsulation to me.  Arrays are too low level a data structure.  Think about Java collections like List.

Answer (score 2):

Add return statement in your `multiplegradeinputs()` method:

```
public String multiplegradeinputs()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <multiplegradeinputs.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("Enter the Grade of the student#" + i +" : ");
     grade = scan.nextInt();
     multiplegradeinputs[i] = grade;
  }
  return null; //Add this line
}
```

Or change your methods to void return type if they dont return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Class names have to be capitalized in java, so instead of

```
 public class students
```

you should write

```
 public class Students
```

Also instead of writing

```
keyboard.nextInt();
```

You should write

```
Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

This is mainly because java is full of bugs and technical specifications that you won't find easily. Let me know if this fixes it for you, since you didn't post the exact error message you got.

As for the error that you pointed out, it's because your function expects a String as a return value no matter what, so either change that to void if you can or return a null string. To do that just add the following line at the very end of the method.

```
return null;
```

Comment: I have seen the parseInt on line researching a bit, we have not gone over this however in class, I was trying to do with with only knowing the bare minimum of java

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return value in the `multiplegradeinputs()` method.

Comment: i can remove the question mark because he/she is missing the return value of string and this causes compile error :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Student object which holds the properties of the student, e.g. Name and Grades. You should then store all the student objects in some kind of data structure such as an array list in the students class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer provided by @hitz

You have a bug in the for loops:

```
for(int i = 1; i <multiplegradeinputs.length; i++)

for(int i = 1; i < multipleStudent.length; i++)
```

You will never populated `multiplegradeinputs[0]` and `multipleStudent[0]` because you start the loop at `index == 1` and thus you will have only 9 student names stored instead of 10.

Change to:

```
for(int i = 0; i <multiplegradeinputs.length; i++)

for(int i = 0; i < multipleStudent.length; i++)
```

Remember even though the length in 10, the indices always start with 0 in Java and in your case will end with 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Student
   {

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private String name;
private int grade;
private int[] multiplegradeinputs = new int[10];
private String[] multipleStudent = new String[10];

public Student()
{
}

public Student(String n, int g)
{
  name = n;
  grade = g;
}

public  String setMultipleStudents()
{
  String n = "";
  for(int i = 1; i < multipleStudent.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("Enter student #" + i +" name: " );
     n = scan.nextLine();
     multipleStudent[i] = n;

  }

  return null;
}



public void multiplegradeinputs()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <multiplegradeinputs.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("Enter the Grade of the student#" + i +" : ");
     grade = scan.nextInt();
     multiplegradeinputs[i] = grade;
  }
}

public String toString()
{
  String temp = "";
   for(int i = 1; i < multipleStudent.length; i++)
  {
     temp += multipleStudent[i] + " ";
  }

  return temp;

}
}
```

this is the 2nd class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class students
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("How many students?: ");
  int numofstudents = keyboard.nextInt();

  Student s = new Student();

  s.setMultipleStudents();
  s.toString();


  System.out.println("Enter the Grade for the student: ");
  int gradeofstudnets = keyboard.nextInt();


   }
}
```